# How to install cgal on CentOS 7(or CentOS 6)?

Tags: centos, cgal

I want to install cgal module on CentOS7(or CentOS6). it needs for pgrouting to use PostGIS.
I have been install cgal with [CGAL Manual Installation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html). But I didn't installed. And tried to install with [PGRouting Installation](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/doc/src/installation/installation.html). But it also failed to install.

Please help me to install cgal library on CentOS7(or CentOS6).

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? Did you install cmake, boost, gmp and mpfr?

Comment: yes, I installed it from source.

Answer (score 1):

I am 3 years late but it might help others.

The CGAL package is available from [Springdale Linux (SDL) / PUIAS Linux](https://springdale.math.ias.edu/).

You can add the [puias.repo](https://gist.github.com/yuikns/704cc2d672624e5c56d7) to `/etc/yum.repo.d/puias.repo`.

Alternatively, just add the `puias_computational` repo.

1. add the gpg keys

```
sudo curl -o /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puias http://springdale.math.ias.edu/data/puias/7/x86_64/os/RPM-GPG-KEY-puias
sudo curl -o /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-springdale http://springdale.math.ias.edu/data/puias/7/x86_64/os/RPM-GPG-KEY-springdale
```

2. add the repo, i.e. create the file `/etc/yum.repo.d/puiascomp.repo` with content

```
[puias_computational]
name=PUIAS computational Base $releasever - $basearch
mirrorlist=http://puias.math.ias.edu/data/puias/computational/$releasever/$basearch/mirrorlist
#baseurl=http://puias.math.ias.edu/data/puias/computational/$releasever/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puias
```

3. now you should be able to install cgal

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install CGAL.x86_64 CGAL-demos-source.x86_64 CGAL-debuginfo.x86_64
```

Note, always be sure you understand what the commands you run are doing, especially when the use `sudo`.